# Python all possible combinations/permutation of X items and of length X+1

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I've been searching everywhere but can't find a thing for my issue.
Let's say I've got three numbers : ['1','2','3'].

I want, using itertool or not, all possible combinations/permutations with a length of 4 and I only want combinations containing these 3 numbers (I don't want '1111' or '1221' and so).

The wanted result would be like that :
1 2 3 1
1 1 2 3
2 2 3 1

Comment: what about 2 3 2 1 ?

Comment: The questions is not clear. On one hand it says "I don't want '1111' or '1221' and so", but on the other hand '1123' or '2231' should be allowed. What is your criterium? Also, if the set consists of ['1','2','3'] only but 4 values should be in a result, how shell we avoid repetition?

Comment: I couldn't explain well what I wanted, but @Aven Desta gave me what I exactly wanted, thank for posting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as irep
res = [' '.join(x) for x in irep('123',4) if {'1','2','3'}.issubset(x)]

# output
# ['1123', '1223', '1233']
```

OR

```
from itertools import product
res= [' '.join(x) for x in product('123',repeat=4) if {'1','2','3'}.issubset(x)]
# output
# ['1123', '1132', '1213', '1223', '1231', '1232', '1233',
# '1312', '1321', '1322', '1323', '1332', '2113', '2123', 
# '2131', '2132', '2133', '2213', '2231', '2311', '2312', 
# '2313', '2321', '2331', '3112', '3121', '3122', '3123', 
# '3132', '3211', '3212', '3213', '3221', '3231', '3312', '3321']
```

Comment: The second one was exactly what I was searching for ! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```py
import itertools

elements = ['1', '2', '3']
permutations = [''.join(combination) for combination in 
                itertools.product(elements, repeat = 4) if 
                all(elem in combination for elem in elements)]
```

Does this produce what you are looking for?

The code produces the following output:

`['1123', '1132', '1213', '1223', '1231', '1232', '1233', '1312', '1321', '1322', '1323', '1332', '2113', '2123', '2131', '2132', '2133', '2213', '2231', '2311', '2312', '2313', '2321', '2331', '3112', '3121', '3122', '3123', '3132', '3211', '3212', '3213', '3221', '3231', '3312', '3321']`

Comment: Yup! This one works as well, thank you for the share!